# babel.loader and pluginPass.CallExpression error

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm getting a babel error that nobody else in my group is getting, there are a couple of them that look like this:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/component/CheckoutPayments/CheckoutPayments.component.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: /Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/DPF/frontend/src/app/component/CheckoutPayments/CheckoutPayments.component.js: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at PluginPass.CallExpression (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/DPF/frontend/node_modules/babel-plugin-console-source/index.js:30:47)
    at newFn (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/DPF/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:179:21)
    at NodePath._call (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/DPF/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:55:20)
    at NodePath.call (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/DPF/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:42:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/DPF/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:90:31)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/DPF/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:112:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/DPF/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:84:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/DPF/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:140:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/DPF/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:84:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/DPF/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:97:18)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/DPF/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:112:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/DPF/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:79:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/DPF/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:138:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/DPF/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:84:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/DPF/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:97:18)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/bryanrasmussen/projects/DPF/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:112:16)
 @ ./src/app/route/Checkout/Checkout.container.js 46:0-96 95:76-82 95:84-93
 @ ./src/app/route/Checkout/index.js
 @ ./src/app/route/index.js
 @ ./src/app/index.js
```

there is no property value being referred to anywhere in the actual code which makes me think it is a relic of the babel compilation. At any rate because of this it is particularly hard to understand what babel could be complaining about.

My babelrc is

```
{
  "presets": ["airbnb"],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-replace-object-assign", { "moduleSpecifier": "object.assign" }],
    [
      "module-resolver", {
      "root": "./",
      "alias": {
        "Style": "./src/app/style/",
        "Component": "./src/app/component/",
        "Route": "./src/app/route/",
        "Store": "./src/app/store/",
        "Util": "./src/app/util/",
        "Query": "./src/app/query/",
        "Type": "./src/app/type/",
        "SourceRoute": "../../../../../vendor/scandipwa/source/src/app/route/"
      }
    }
    ]
  ]
}
```

And my babel config is

```
const presets = [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-react'
];

const plugins = [
    'transform-rebem-jsx',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    [
        'module-resolver', {
            root: './',
            alias: {
                Style: './src/app/style/',
                Component: './src/app/component/',
                Route: './src/app/route/',
                Store: './src/app/store/',
                Util: './src/app/util/',
                Query: './src/app/query/',
                Type: './src/app/type/',
                SourceStyle: '../../../../../vendor/scandipwa/source/src/app/style/',
                SourceComponent: '../../../../../vendor/scandipwa/source/src/app/component/',
                SourceRoute: '../../../../../vendor/scandipwa/source/src/app/route/',
                SourceStore: '../../../../../vendor/scandipwa/source/src/app/store/',
                SourceUtil: '../../../../../vendor/scandipwa/source/src/app/util/',
                SourceQuery: '../../../../../vendor/scandipwa/source/src/app/query/',
                SourceType: '../../../../../vendor/scandipwa/source/src/app/type/'
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        'console-source', {
            segments: 1
        }
    ]
];

module.exports = {
    presets,
    plugins
};
```

babel components are

```
"@babel/core": "^7.10.3",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.1",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.10.3",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.10.3",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.3",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.10.3",
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
"babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
"babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
"babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
"babel-minify-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.1",
"babel-plugin-console-source": "^2.0.5",
"babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-rebem-jsx": "^0.3.3",
"babel-plugin-transform-replace-object-assign": "^2.0.0",
"babel-preset-airbnb": "^3.2.0",
```

webpack version is `"webpack": "^4.43.0",`

similar problems that people have had do not seem to be exactly this one https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/674

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue. Replaced the package.json & package-lock.json file with the original and it started to work.

Screenshot:
[image: Difference in Package.json]

You can updated the package.json from this below file locations:

- vendor/scandipwa/source/package.json
- vendor/scandipwa/source/package-lock.json

Comment: This can happen if you run `npm update` to update all packages to the latest version - which you shouldn't do if you don't want to risk breaking something.